# Error string in catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i have the following code which show error from a string when there is a error

is there any way that i can make this in catch block?

```
  main()
    {
    try
    {
    if (a==1)
    {
     string = "error1"
    }
    elseif (a==2)
    {
     string = "error2"
    }
    }
    }
    catch (e)
    {


    }
```

Like below:

i have the following code which show error from a string when there is a error

is there any way that i can make this in catch block?

```
main()
{
try
{
}
}

catch (e)
{

if (a==1)
{
 string = "error1"
}
elseif (a==2)
{
 string = "error2"
}

}
```

Comment: What the heck is this? Please, rewrite all the code and post again. That is not C#.

Comment: Were this code really C# (you need a `try` statement plus some other stuff) then it would work assuming that the value of `a` was set when the exception was raised and that your `string` variable was declared outside the `try`.

Answer (score 3):

You're making an absolute hash of the syntax I'm afraid. I suggest that before anything else you go read the [MSDN article on `try-catch` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx). The syntax and semantics of exception handling should then start to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is an **improper** version, it may well answer your question:

```
    try {

        if (a == 1) {
            throw new Exception("error1");
        } else if (a == 2) {
            throw new Exception("error2");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Errormessage = " + ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to put logic into a catch block?

You should read up on exception handling to see what the correct syntax is, and why you would use it in the first place.

[http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson15.aspx](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533925)

A good book on c# might also be useful, you could try [Essential C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533925) as it is useful for beginners...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to use exception handling.
Exceptions should be exceptional, and not used for conditional logic.

All you need is your if ... else block.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this.

```
 try {

 if(a == 1) {throw new Exception("Erorr1");}

 if(a == 2) {throw new Exception("Erorr2");}

 } catch(Exception e) {
   /*Do something with exception or look below */
 }
```

Here you raise an error by throwing an Exception that is served in catch clause

or this

```
try{
 /*Some code that cause an Exception*/
} catch(Exception e) { //Exception describe the type which wold be caught. 

 string errorType = String.Empty;

 var a = -1; //Assign to it smtg from e that You want to check

 if(a == 1) {
   errorType = "erro1";
 }
 else  if (a == 2) {
   errorType = "erro2";
 }

 /* More Your code*/

}
```

hire You do something with error type that You caught.

But first of all read about something that You want to use in Your code.

Comment: This is probably the worse practise for using exceptions.
Making a decision based on the value of a variable is not the reason one should throw an exception, its the reason one should use an 'if' statement.

Comment: It is a debatable practice, for instance when we have the null is some  field/parameter system throws an error when we try to work with it but if we display that null on the console nothing wrong happen. Also a calculation can be stop this way in some complex algorithms. Nevertheless we can only assume what SmartestVEGA wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Baseball Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2814519#2814519) and why not to do it.